# How to get multiple elements that use angular directives on one line rather then two

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In the code below, "Statement Overview" is appearing on one line and the rest " - Statement" with the gif are appearing on the line below it.
I'd like them all to be on the same line. Any one know how I can do this?

By the way, removing style="display: block;" breaks another area of the angular code so I need to leave that part in. Any help would be appreciated to get this all in on one line.

```
<tr class="Title">
    <td colspan="5">Statement Overview
        <span id="loadingStatement" style="display: block;" ng-hide="loadingContent">
             - Statement
            <span ng-bind="status"></span>
            <img alt="Updating" src="/User/Content/Images/Spinner.gif" />
        </span>
        <span id="updatedat" class="Right" ng-bind="updatedat"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: APply `style="display: inline-block;"`

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
<tr class="Title">
    <td colspan="5">Statement Overview
        <span id="loadingStatement"  ng-hide="loadingContent"> - Statement
    <span ng-bind="status"></span>
       <img alt="Updating" src="/User/Content/Images/Spinner.gif" />
    </span>
    <span id="updatedat" class="Right" ng-bind="updatedat"></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
#loadingStatement {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

chek the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5sctgf3x/

Comment: Thank you but for some reason, in IE 10 (the main cause of this whole issue), the solution of removing 'display: block;' or changing it to display: inline-block; will break other areas of the code and not display angular data until the browser is resized. 

Another way to get this all in one line you guys know of?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to use ng-hide in another area of the page. Odd fix fix for an odd problem.

```
<tr>                        
    <td colspan="6">
       <div ng-hide="loadingContent">                               
          <img alt="Loading" src="/Images/blank.gif" />
        </div>                      
    </td>
</tr>
```